# Expectation of an integral depending on Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have a question which even if it involves a Brownian motion it shouldn't require too much effort.

Suppose I have a brownian Motion $W_t$ which has density $$p(t,x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left(- \frac{x^2}{2t} \right), \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}$$

and I need to compute

$$ E[\int_0^t f'(W_r) dr]$$

where $f,f',f''$  are bounded and $f \in C^2$.

How can I move? I need to use the definition of expectation, and using the fact that I know the density of $W_r$, but the derivative confuses me a lot. **I can't use Ito calculus**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fubini's theorem, your integral equals
$$\int_0^t E[f'(W_r)]\,dr$$
and since you know the density, you can compute $E[f'(W_r)]$ with an appropriate integral.

Comment: $E[f'(W_r)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f'(x)  p_t(x) dx$, rigth?

Comment: Right, except $p_t$ should be $p_r$.  You may consider integrating by parts here if it helps.

Comment: Just to be clear, but with $p_t(x)$ I just mean the density, not the derivative of the density... should I consider $\partial_t p_t(x)$, instead?

Comment: Could you please be more explicit? I don't undertstand what you mean with $p_r$

Comment: Just that the time parameter on the left side is $r$ instead of $t$, so it should also be $r$ on the right side to be consistent.  It is not the derivative of the density.

Comment: @Vefhug: The integral in the first comment must certainly be with respect to $x$ if it's to equal the expectation.  I don't see a good way to use the fact that $\partial_t p(t,x)= \partial_{xx} p(t,x)$ (which by the way is missing a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$).  You could integrate by parts twice with respect to $x$, but then you'll have the antiderivative of $f$ appearing, which doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: Yes the $\frac{1}{2}$ was missing. My goal is actually to prove $f(W_t) - f(W_0) - \int_0^t \frac{1}{2} f''(W_r) \, dr$ has constant expectation, so I started by doing $f(W_t) - f(W_0)= \int_0^t f'(W_r)dr$ and then took the expectation. But from your last comment it seems that I'm in the wrong way.. Is there any other way to prove it?

Comment: @Vefhug: Aha, now it becomes more clear what you are after.  First of all, $f(W_t) - f(W_0)= \int_0^t f'(W_r)dr$ is wrong. The fundamental theorem of calculus would give you $\frac{d}{dr} [f(W_r)]$ inside the integral, and that does not equal $f'(W_r)$; you would also need something like $dW_r/dr$ because of the chain rule.  Unfortunately $dW_r/dr$ does not exist, so the whole thing falls apart.

Comment: @Vefhug: The correct strategy here is to look at $E[\int_0^t \frac{1}{2} f''(W_r)\,dr]$.  Interchange the integral with the expectation and write the expectation as an integral against $p(t,x)\,dx$.  Integrate by parts twice to see $\partial_{xx} p(t,x)$ appearing, replace it by $2\partial_t p(t,x)$, and then see where you stand.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, though I don't really like your notation in $\int_0^t \partial_t p(t,x) \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx dt$ - you have $x$ appearing outside the $dx$ integral.  In order to use the fundamental theorem of calculus as you want, you really need to interchange the integrals to put the time integral on the inside.  (Also, I think it's bad style to use $t$ for both the limit of integration and the dummy variable - I suggest you keep using $r$ as your dummy variable.)

Comment: Many thanks !

So, $$ \int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \partial_r p(r,x)dx dr = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_0^t \partial_r p(r,x)  f(x) dr dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} (p(t,x)-p(0,x)) f(x) dx $$ and the thesis follow by noticing that $E[f(W_r)]= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) p(r,x)dx$

Comment: Now it should be okay, right? I couldn't edit my previous comment so I wrote a new one!

Comment: @Vefhug: Yes, exactly.